# QGIS - Execute SQL Failure

Tags: qgis, sql, query, database

I've written an SQL query which works in the query section of the QGIS DB Manager.

```
SELECT Max(S_order), SegmentID, S_Order, Length, Buff_Segme, Buff_Order, Buff_Lengt, Buff_Uniqu 
FROM "Channel_Network_Within_Buffers_With_SSSI_Ref"
GROUP BY "Channel_Network_Within_Buffers_With_SSSI_Ref"."Buff_Uniqu"
```

[image]

Now, I want to use that query in the `Execute SQL` tool as part of a process model. I've copied the exact same SQL query into `Execute SQL` but I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\ExecuteSQL.py", line 160, in processAlgorithm
>   vLayer.fields(), vLayer.wkbType() if geometry_type != 1 else 1, vLayer.crs())
>   Exception: unknown
>   Execution failed after 0.28 seconds

This is how the `Execute SQL` query is set up:

[image]

Why would the same SQL query work in the DB Manager query builder but fail in the `Execute SQL` Tool?

Comment: Please include SQL as text in the body of the question. Screenshots are not legible on all devices, and require each person who would want to reproduce your issue to retype the code.

Comment: Added SQL Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify `No geometry` for the geometry type.

[image]